# How to fix view-source font problem in firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, font-family, view-source, font-style

when i go to the any page view-source in Mozilla Firefox browser i have problem that you can see in screenshot...
[codes font in view-source of Mozilla Firefox browser are like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEYaG.png)

and that's where the problem come from, when i change '-moz-fixed' font it will solve the problem  but i always have to do this :(

[here in this picture you can see what i am talking about...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzuen.png)

Answer (score 0):

apparently it was firefox bug and it fixed by their update updating because i didn't change any things and no longer have this issue

[here you can see it's working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsUSZ.jpg)